# MYSQL thowing an syntax error inster into

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the code. I´m using MYSQL. It throws a syntax error, and i can´t find the error in this simple command.

```
 insert into l_mes (id_mes, desc_mes, id_anio)
        values (201601, Ene 2016, 2016), (201602, Feb 2016, 2016)
```

Comment: Problem is here "Ene 2016".  If that's a string literal, enclose it in single quotes, `..., 'Ene 2016', ...`. Same for "'Feb 2016".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `'` ticks (single quotes) around `'strings'`:

```
insert into l_mes (id_mes, desc_mes, id_anio)
    values (201601, 'Ene 2016', 2016), 
           (201602, 'Feb 2016', 2016)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data types here, you're missing quotes around your string values.

```
 insert into l_mes (id_mes, desc_mes, id_anio)
        values (201601, 'Ene 2016', 2016), (201602, 'Feb 2016', 2016)
```